# GRUB can't load Ubuntu, instead falls to initramfs

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs

Yesterday I was trying to change my boot args to pass my second GPU to VM. I've done it successfully a couple of weeks ago. But now, for some reason, the same GRUB selection can't boot. The GRUB menu comes up, I select any of the options, it tries to boot, then initramfs comes up with the error `boot args require root= Parameter` even though there is.

I have a secondary Ubuntu 20.04 on a USB drive, I configure its GRUB to boot into Ubuntu 20.04 on the hard drive, and it boots. When I could boot into Ubuntu on the hard drive, I tried to do it the other way. Booting into Ubuntu on the USB from GRUB on the hard drive, and it fails.

I've tried reinstalling GRUB (`grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda`), mkinitramfs, reinstalling grub-customizer, customizing GRUB on hard drive with Ubuntu on USB via changing environment, copying the boot script from USB to hard drive with grub-customizer on both Ubuntus.

Pastebin from Boot-Repair (before repair): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CBr699jv3r/. Part of the Pastebin of the Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary is shown below.

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda4 starts 
                       at sector 1953318912. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, sda4 starts at sector 4883970048.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS CurrentSession on sda2
OS#2:   Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on sdb3
OS#3:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda4

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-48-generic root=UUID=7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727 ro quiet splash
df -Th / : /dev/sda2      ext4  2.3T  1.9T  261G  89% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F7 from Award Software International, Inc.
This installed-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda4    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb3    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb3    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  customized, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  fstab-has-goodBOOT, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  customized, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 2.75 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk identifier: 53FA307E-15D6-42AF-924E-E969393ED491
           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1        2048     194559     192512    94M BIOS boot
sda2      194560 4883967999 4883773440   2.3T Linux filesystem
sda4  4883970048 5860532223  976562176 465.7G Microsoft basic data
Disk sdb: 28.67 GiB, 30765219840 bytes, 60088320 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x4047f93c
      Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *        2048   999423   997376  487M 83 Linux
sdb2         999424 20531199 19531776  9.3G 83 Linux
sdb3       20531200 60088319 39557120 18.9G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:3001GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3:;
1:1049kB:99.6MB:98.6MB:::bios_grub;
2:99.6MB:2501GB:2500GB:ext4:ubuntu:;
4:2501GB:3001GB:500GB:ntfs:win10old:msftdata;
sdb:30.8GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:SanDisk Cruzer Blade:;
1:1049kB:512MB:511MB:ext2::boot;
2:512MB:10.5GB:10.0GB:ext4::;
3:10.5GB:30.8GB:20.3GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                             
├─sda1                                               cdd316f1-8ba6-4dbf-ada9-8d394e7d5106       
├─sda2 ext4     7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727 6350c9fc-a9c3-417e-9c4b-6d928f725b04       ubuntu
└─sda4 ntfs     109E03B29E039000                     24c61a43-c524-4fcb-9aa4-23b7030c7687       win10old
sdb                                                                                             
├─sdb1 ext2     643df8ce-4bc3-4c00-a066-42d128b98097 4047f93c-01                                
├─sdb2 ext4     2e899ba0-a146-4282-8fdf-ad7456d80327 4047f93c-02                                
└─sdb3 ext4     0b68fe75-a179-4b4d-8362-22dfd343fadb 4047f93c-03                                

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                261G  84% /
/dev/sda4              151.9G  67% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sdb1              285.4M  34% /media/alienus/643df8ce-4bc3-4c00-a066-42d128b98097
/dev/sdb2                  8G   8% /media/alienus/2e899ba0-a146-4282-8fdf-ad7456d80327
/dev/sdb3                8.1G  51% /media/alienus/0b68fe75-a179-4b4d-8362-22dfd343fadb

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda2              ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda4              fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1              ext2            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
/dev/sdb2              ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
/dev/sdb3              ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
```

*Note: I do not use the Windows on sda4. It's just a copy from my old drive, and intentionally it's unbootable.*

GRUB script from hard drive:

```
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2 --hint='hd0,gpt2'  7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727
fi
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-48-generic root=UUID=7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
```

GRUB script from USB:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727
fi
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-48-generic root=UUID=7b9b093f-077c-4693-a0ae-93e464d52727 ro quiet splash  $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In this question answer site please don't put [SOLVED] in the question title and put the answer inside the question. Please click on the button **Answer Your Own Question** and put a detailed answer to your problem there. After the required waiting time accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark  next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will indicate your question has been answered correctly, and help others. Please read the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) and learn how to use this site properly.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for the notice. I've made the necessary changes in the question and posted a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on a live USB solved the issue of not loading the root partition. But it installed only the 5.15.0-41-generic kernel, and I've had problems with this kernel. So I booted live USB again, mounted the hard drive with

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt (root partition)
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot (required if separate boot partition)
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

And used  `sudo chroot /mnt` to switch into the system.

After this I've reinstalled the GRUB, (as I was root, no sudo needed)

```
grub-mkdevicemap
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

After this, I got more kernel and recovery options.

While booting, I selected the option with 5.13.0-48-generic kernel, which was working fine for me. Then I edited the default option from 5.15.0-41-generic to 5.13.0-48-generic via grub-customizer. After making sure this booted without an issue, I added a second GRUB option with boot parameters that blocks my second GPU and rebooted a couple time switching between normal and
GPU pass, and seeing it booting in both options without and issue, i can call this issue solved.